# including external javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to include external javascript to a document. Let's say that external js has the following code.

```
function myFunction() {
  console.log("hello");
}
```

and I include it from console by

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "http://myjs";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

but then I still get myFunction() is undefined error. The function is being called from `php` file included on the page somehow. Interestingly, appending my external javascript right after the head tag in the document was not enough for it to precede the function call from the loaded php file.

Q: how do I ensure that I include my javascript BEFORE the php file given my situation?

EDIT: this is the hierarchy of all the sources

```
mysubsite.com
  myfolder
    mypage.html

mysite.com
  myfolder
    main.php
    problem.php
```

problem.php is calling function `myFunction()` but it's not included anywhere yet. So I try to define the function in an outside js file and include it in mypage.html, but problem.php still comes before the included javascript in mypage.html

EDIT:

I think the real problem is that I am dealing with an iframe that's included inside a main document. In this case, is there a way to include my external javascript file inside the main document from console? Including scripts from console only affects the iframe instead of the main document.

Comment: write the php code you use to call that function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is fine, but then you have to wait for the file to load. Most browsers will raise the `load` event on the script element although some older versions of IE use `onreadystatechanged` instead. But since you're using jQuery (from the tags on the question), you don't have to worry about that, you can just use [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/):

```
$.getScript("http://myjs", function() {
    // The script has been loaded, you can call myFunction now
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer T.J.
I tried this already unfortunately. The problem is that the predefined php file needs to call the function in myjs. After I include myjs via getScript, it seems that the php file still cannot call the function. Suppose myFunction() is defined in the newly included javascript file my.js. I can call myFunction from console, but the `php` file that's loaded from server still cannot call `myFunction()`. I am not familiar with php and not sure how to solve this.

Comment: I assume the entire website consists of multiple iframes, and the php that's making the function call is in the outside iframe while I am including myjs script only in the inside iframe.

Comment: @MaximusS: The PHP is running *on the server*. The JavaScript is running *on the client*. The PHP code cannot call the JavaScript. All it can do is output JavaScript code that calls the JavaScript. It sounds like it's doing that, but the code it outputs is running before the script file is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is always included before JavaScript. PHP is executed by the server before it's sent to the client, and JavaScript is executed by the client.

Why can't you just put a regular `<script type="text/javascript" src="http:/myjs"></script>` in your `head`?